# Is there a way in Cypress to view all stubbed endpoints?

Tags: cypress

I might be thinking about this all wrong, basically I just want a quick dirty method to list all stubbed routes at runtime.
Would there be a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst writing the question I saw that cypress already provides this info in the routes tab when running a spec.